# Pandas: Unable to convert strings ('-0.0','-1.34') to float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, type-conversion

I have been trying to convert the `dtype` of a column in my panda dataframe from `str` to `float64` but am get the following error:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float:'‐0.0'`

I confirmed the prior dtype of a value under that column to be `str` using :
`type(df.loc[500,'expt_pIC50'])`

I attempted the conversion via : `df['expt_pIC50']=df['expt_pIC50'].astype(np.double)`

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong and/or link an alternate method to convert the dtype ? Any help would be much appreciated !!

Thank you

**Expanded Logs:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_276/1411409380.py in <module>
----> 1 df['expt_pIC50']=df['expt_pIC50'].astype(np.double)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5813         else:
   5814             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5815             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5816             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5817 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    416 
    417     def astype(self: T, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise") -> T:
--> 418         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    419 
    420     def convert(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    325                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    326                 else:
--> 327                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    328             except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    329                 if not ignore_failures:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    589         values = self.values
    590 
--> 591         new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    592 
    593         new_values = maybe_coerce_values(new_values)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy, errors)
   1307 
   1308     try:
-> 1309         new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1310     except (ValueError, TypeError):
   1311         # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_array(values, dtype, copy)
   1255 
   1256     else:
-> 1257         values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1258 
   1259     # in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fyp_al\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1199     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr.dtype) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
   1200         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
-> 1201         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1202 
   1203     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '‐0.0'
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data in that column?

Comment: An example would be this sample, `CHEMBL1394474 737823 ‐0.0 4.8879 TRN`, under 5 columns separated by a space where '-0.0' is the data under the column 'expt_pIC50'. And I wish to change the dtype of this column to `float64`

Answer (score 3):

Your `‐` in `'‐0.0'` is a unicode U+2010 character (HYPHEN), which, while visually identical, is very different from `-` (unicode U+002D; HYPHEN-MINUS), the classical dash/minus character found on most keyboards and used by python as minus sign.

You need to replace the character with a classical minus before conversion to float:

```
df['your_col'].str.replace('\u2010', '-', regex=False).astype(float)
```